# Berkeley DB C++ showing incorrect key-value string data

Tags: c++, berkeley-db, vcpkg

I have installed Berkeley DB with VCPKG.

I am trying to store simple key-value with Berkeley DB. like

> fruit = apple

```cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <db.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vcruntime_string.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DATABASE "access.db"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DB* dbp;
    DBT key, data;
    int ret;
    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        cout << "db_create :" << db_strerror(ret) << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "db_created or exists" << endl;

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp,
        NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);
        cout << "can not open db" << DATABASE << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "opened " << DATABASE << endl;
    }
    const char* fruit = "fruit";
    const char* apple = "apple";
    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    key.data = &fruit;
    key.size = sizeof(fruit);
    data.data = &apple;
    data.size = sizeof(apple);

    if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0)
        cout << "db: key stored :" << (const char*)key.data << endl;
    else
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->put");

    DBT key1, value1;
    memset(&key1, 0, sizeof(key1));
    memset(&value1, 0, sizeof(value1));
    key1.data = &fruit;
    key1.size = sizeof(fruit);

    if ((ret = dbp->get(dbp, NULL, &key1, &value1, 0)) == 0)
        cout << "db: value fetched :" << (const char*)value1.data << endl;
    else
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->get");

    return 0;
}
```

the `DBT` DB transaction instance expects a void pointer `void *` as input, so I am passing the reference. The code works, however when I cast the data value from `DBT` it shows junk/illegible characters. I dont know what the issue is

#### Output

```
db: key stored :£┴₧÷
db: value fetched :ñ┴₧÷
```

### Things I tried:

- Used casting with (string *)

```
db: key stored :000000C6B78FFC68
db: value fetched :0000025996F56C70
```

- Cast with (char *)

```
db: key stored :£┴┘à÷
db: value fetched :ñ┴┘à÷
```

- Cast with (const char *)

```
db: key stored :£┴₧÷
db: value fetched :ñ┴₧÷
```

- Cast with *(const char *)

```
db: key stored :£
db: value fetched :ñ
```

- Pasted values in Notepad++ and changed Encoding to see if it gives plain text as desired

---

How do I get readable text from Berkeley DB? Am I doing something wrong while storing data itself?

I am a beginner in C++, so I am not getting what else to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution was to change datatype of key values from constant character pointer `const char *` to char array.

```cpp
char fruit[sizeof("fruit")] = "fruit";
char apple[sizeof("apple")] = "apple";
```

Additionally , even using `string` instead of `const char *` for key-values gives similar issue as mentioned in the question, somehow I could make it work only with char array.
Reference : [BerkeleyDB.example](https://github.com/liuqun/BerkeleyDB.example)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, "*I am doing something wrong while storing data itself?*". Fixing a toy example so that it works without explaining what's wrong with it is not very helpful.

Comment: *How do I get a readable text from BerkeleyDB?* was the main question.
This anwer solves it. 
*What am I doing wrong?* - storing reference to const char pointer instead of reference to the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* fruit = "fruit";
```

This means `sizeof(fruit)` is the size of a `const char *` on your platform. It also means `&fruit` is where this particular pointer is stored on your platform. Given those two things:

```
data.data = &apple;
data.size = sizeof(apple);
```

Neither of these lines makes any sense. You're supposed to put a pointer to the data in `data`, not a pointer to a `const char *`. You're supposed to put the size of the data in `size`, not the size of a `const char *`.

Try:

```
data.data = (void *) apple;
data.size = strlen(apple);
```

Comment: Can not assign `data.data = apple` because `cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'void *'` Getting compile error

Comment: @Prateek It's much more important that you understand my explanation of what's wrong with your code than that you get the code to work! Fixing this toy example is not nearly as important as understanding the issues involved.

Comment: Yes, I understood your point logically. Helped me to solve it finally. Thanks! BTW the change suggested is giving me `apple²²²²` on the output. Because of using strlen instead of `sizeof`. Toy examples like `how to` sometimes help us figure out the issues.

Asking OPs to try this and that do not answer the questions. They shoould be rather in comments than answer.